# Why are the front and rear slide rails offset on my Craftsman table saw?

Tags: table-saw

I've got a couple of questions regarding a Craftsman table saw (Model 315.228510) that I own.

1. When attaching front rail, it said to match the 6-7/8 mark on right scale to right edge of saw base. The saw has two extensions- one on each side. I noticed the distance from right edge of saw blade is right around 5 inches. What my question was is the purpose of lining up right edge of saw base to the 6-7/8 mark?
2. When attaching front rail and rear rail, the two rails are not the same length-the rear rail is shorter. Is it suppose to be that way? It seems to me you would want it to be same length so that the rip fence could be used the full length.

Comment: To make sure the measurement guide is centered on the blade would my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rear rail is shorter because the rear clamp of the fence does not need as much side to side space as the near side of the fence. Here is a picture of a typical table saw fence:

[image]

Notice how the near side has the widest part of the assembly.

The measurement scale on the front rail is lined up so that the index arrow on the front side of the fence shows the distance from the saw blade to the side of the fence. The recommended distance from your instructions, using the edge of the table as a reference, is an easy setup. However that may only apply specifically to that model saw with a particular fence and a particular thickness of saw blade. Also note in the picture above how the index mark arrow is offset from the actual fence side.